# Get word between 2 strings by using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a return value of "SomeCode SomeAddressHere SecondAddressHere, SomeCityHere, SomeCountryHere"

I would like to return the words **SomeAddressHere** and **SecondAddressHere**

I tried:

```js
var str2 = "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
var str = 'one:two;three';
str2.split(' ')[1].split(',')[0]

console.log(str2);
```

It only returns *Los*, I would like to get the **Los Angeles City** and another thing the city can also have Single space, I would like to get the word after the *SomeCode* and the first *comma*

It Should have the Output: Los Angeles City

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try matching the string from the first space character before the first occurrence of comma.

Try the following way:

```js
var str2 = "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
var str2 = str2.match(/(?<= )([^,]+)/)[0];
console.log(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution.

You can split the string by spaces...

slice the string, take everything from the first index after, (ie "Los Angeles ...)

Join the strings with spaces.

Split them by commas.

Take first index

Hopefully that makes sense.

```js
var str2= "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
console.log(str2.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ").split(",")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split,slice and join

```js
var str2= "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
console.log(str2.split(",")[0].split(" ").slice(1).join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the first word character which is at a word boundary and is *not* the start of the string, then match as many characters as you can until you come to `,`:

```js
var str2 = "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
console.log(
  str2.match(/(?!^)\b\w[^,]+/)[0]
);
```

Or, if `SomeCodeHere` is static, it's easier, since you can just match it:

```js
var str2 = "SomeCodeHere Los Angeles City, California, USA";
console.log(
  str2.match(/SomeCodeHere ([^,]+)/)[1]
);
```